# Can't get value of radio buttons using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a series of radio buttons and a submit button:

```
<input type="radio" name="selectme_resubmit" id="selectme_resubmit1" value="first" /> <label for="selectme_resubmit1">Resubmit with the original submitter</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="selectme_resubmit" id="selectme_resubmit2" value="without" checked /> <label for="selectme_resubmit2">Resubmit without any submitter</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="selectme_resubmit" id="selectme_resubmit3" value="custom" /> <label for="selectme_resubmit3">Resubmit with a custom submitter:</label> <input type="text" name="selectme_custom_submitter" id="selectme_custom_submitter" /><br>
<input type="button" id="selectme_resubmit_button" name="selectme_resubmit2_button" value="Place a submit template" onclick="selectme_act(\'resubmit\')" />
```

I also have the following javascript (with jquery):

```
var typeofsubmit = $("input[name=selectme_resubmit]:checked").val();
console.log(typeofsubmit);
```

However, I get "undefined" in the console, even when I select something... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: when are u calling this javascript?

Comment: $("input[name='selectme_resubmit']:checked") single quote the name

Comment: @hungerpain I call the js within a function, `selectme_act()`

Comment: @user1483482 could u make a fiddle for your problem at jsfiddle.net ? It'll be easier to look at ur mistake

Comment: @hungerpain http://jsfiddle.net/USpb4/ [when i click run, nothing happens...]

Comment: seems to work here : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/USpb4/1/
all i did was to take away those `\` in the `onclick` method..

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and the selector does work. The only issue I found was that you were escaping the `'` character when it was not needed in the `onclick` event

Comment: The selector doesn't work when I call it from within a function, `selectme_act()`, which is called onclick of the submit button

Answer (score 0):

you miss ready function

```
$().ready(function(){
 var typeofsubmit = $("input[name=selectme_resubmit]:checked").val();
  console.log(typeofsubmit);
 });
```

please use ready function before your declaration

and check this link http://jsfiddle.net/FQGuu/

Comment: I run `var typeofsubmit = $("input[name=selectme_resubmit]:checked").val();` inside another function, `selectme_act`, which is called onclick of the button.